# Place data from JSON Array in to a Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I would like to place the data from the $data variable (ajax.php) into my this.products[ ] (store.js) array in the javascript file. How would i do this? Bearing in mind they are in to seperate files, can i link the two?

The ajax.php file returns the database data in webpage as follows:

```
[{"0":"100001","SKU":"100001","1":"Key Ring","Name":"Key Ring","2":"Personalised Key Ring","Description":"Personalised Key Ring","3":"5","Price":"5"}
```

ajax.php

```
<?php
//database settings
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "wrightr");

$result = mysqli_query($connect, "select * from storeitems");

$data = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $data[] = $row;
}
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

store.js - originally this.product[ ] contained LocalStorage values, but i would like then to contain the values from the JSON file in order from the database table.

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------
// store (contains the products)
//
function store() {
    this.products = [
 //example   new product (**field1**, **field2**, **field3**, etc...),
 //example   new product (**field1**, **field2**, **field3**, etc...),        
}
store.prototype.getProduct = function (sku) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++) {
        if (this.products[i].sku == sku)
            return this.products[i];
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You need to use AJAX. There's lots of examples online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use AJAX. Here are two options (you would use this in your `store.js` file)

### Using jQuery [[docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)]

```
$.get('ajax.php', function(resp){
   // do something with resp
   console.log(resp) // [{"0":"100001"...
})
```

### Vanilla JavaScript [[docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)]

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.addEventListener("load", function(){
    if(req.status === 200) { 
        var resp = JSON.parse(req.response)
    }
});
req.open("GET", "ajax.php");
req.send();
```

Comment: how would the data be place into the this.product[ ] array?

Comment: `this.products = resp`

Comment: so i tried this and it worked in the console, but its not reading in to the webpage as i expected as if i put it in manually

Comment: Sorry, guess you'll have to do more testing and research.